# Flexslider isn't working within a Fancybox 2 ajax window

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, flexslider

Hi ran into the following issue. I tried to use Flexslider v.2.1 within a Fancybox v.2.1.3 ajax window. The ajax window pops up but the three images shown are missing the direction nav icons as well as it isn't possible at all to browse through the images.

The relevant html bit looks like the following:

```
<ul class="moodlegrid sectionwrap">
            <li><a class="ajax1" href="projekt1.html"><img title="Projekte1" src="img/projekteblur.jpg" alt="Projekte1" /><img title="Projekte1" src="img/projekte.jpg" alt="Projekte1" /><span class="spiceup">Zum Projekt</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

At the bottom of the index.html page the jQuery part looks like the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="./js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="./js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="./js/jquery.flexslider-2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax1").fancybox({
        type: 'ajax',
        fitToView   : false,
        openOpacity : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '97%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterLoad: function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: true,
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: true,
                slideshow: false
            });}        
    });
});
```

The Flexslider relevant part of the html loaded into the ajax window looks like that:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="img/projekteblur.JPG" alt='Bild' width='530px' height='307px'/></li>
        <li><img src="img/projekte.JPG" alt='Bild' width='530px' height='307px' /></li>
        <li><img src="img/projekteblur.JPG" alt='Bild' width='530px' height='307px' /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Inside the console there aren't any errors at all. If anyone has an idea how to solve that issue it would be great. Thanks in advance r.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem. The problem is that the dom needs to be reloaded after the ajax load before you can fire flexslider.

I'm a frontend developer so for the sake of simplicity and speed I put the flexslider call in the ajax load. Like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="img/projekteblur.JPG" alt='Bild' width='530px' height='307px'/></li>
        <li><img src="img/projekte.JPG" alt='Bild' width='530px' height='307px' /></li>
        <li><img src="img/projekteblur.JPG" alt='Bild' width='530px' height='307px' /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$("flexslider ul.slides").flexslider();
```

This works for me..

Comment: Sorry for the late followup. But what do you mean by "put the flexslider call in the ajax load"? Place another script tag at the end of the html file loaded inside the ajax modal window and load flexslider there?

Comment: I must admit it's not the most beautiful solution but it works. The flexslider has to be (re)fired after loading the new content.